# How to only get Gmail notification with certain tag(s)?

Tags: notifications, gmail, sync

I get too many Gmail notifications so my phone beeps too often and is annoying. How to only get Gmail notification with certain tag(s)?  For example, only "Important" ones as I'm using Priority inboxes with Gmail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't mention what version of the app you're using or which OS version, but this is how I do it on my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0.

- Open Gmail app
- Open the overflow menu (three vertical dots) and choose `Settings`
- Tap the email account you want to use
- Under "Data Usage" tap "Manage labels"

  - You'll see your labels there, including "pseudo-labels" like "Starred" and "Important"
- Tap the label for which you want notifications (in your case, "Important")
- If not already on, turn on `Sync messages` (either last 30 days or All)
- Tap the checkbox for `Email notifications`

  - Choose your options (ringtone, whether to vibrate or not, whether to notify once or not)

You can have different notifications per label per account, which is nice, but if you overdo it you'll have way too many notifications in your notification bar.

Comment: This also lets you get notifications for a specific email type, by setting a filter to a dedicated tag....